# how to improve the performance of in sql expression

Tags: sql

I am now execution a sql similar to below：

```
select * from table_name where num in (123,124....,210) and type='a'
```

the records of the table_name is around 1500000, so the execution time is very long, is there any idea that I could improve the efficiency?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using index in where clause? so specify columns when fetch data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query, you want an index on `table_name(type, num)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add index on `type and num` column

Comment: Upvoting the existing answer is better for future visitors than posting an answer that is essentially already posted 11 hours before